# Specify name of table types in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

Create a new database in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and then create a new table type with the following command

```
CREATE TYPE typeMyType AS TABLE (ID INT)
```

Now execute the following query

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME (object_id) AS ObjectName, *
FROM   sys.indexes 
WHERE  index_id <= 1
ORDER BY ObjectName
```

This will show you that an object of type HEAP was created which is fine as the data for *typeMyType* has to be stored somewhere.
But the object is called **TT_typeMyType_01142BA1** in my case.

Question:
Why isn't it called **typeMyType** and how can I overwrite this obviously server generated name?

Comment: The correct place to look for the metadata is `sys.types`.

Comment: Or `sys.table_types` might be more appropriate actually. Shows up in both but only the second one exposes `type_table_object_id`

Comment: It shows up in other places also.  See my answer below.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA - The type itself only shows up in `sys.types` and `sys.table_types`. SQL Server creates another internal object in the `sys` schema that shows up in the other places.

Comment: I looked up the link you provided.  So the schema is [sys]. for the table?

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA - Yes. It looks like it stores metadata about it in a similar way to creating an instance of the type (though in user database and nothing in `sys.partitions`)

Comment: But is the statistics updated for the object or just a place holder?  When you declare an object of type X, it uses tempdb for allocation.

Comment: Good discussion, Tx Martin!

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA - Yes agree, This dummy object is just a handy way of storing the various table oriented metadata about columns/indexes/constraints I suppose.

Comment: OK so I also voted to close this as a duplicate. Too bad I couldn't find the other question first.  
Also I assume that we can't provide the name for this object as it is always generated by the server.

Answer (score 1):

The table type is listed in several places that can be looked at via the following system tables (sys.sysobjects, sys.indexes, sys.table_types and sys.types).

I can understand that table_types is a subset of types.  Therefore, those two places are where to look for my table type AssociativeArray in my AdventureWorks2012 database.

The question I have is why is it looking like a table in sysobjects and sysindexes?

We have not defined any use for the variable yet.  However, it looks like a table.  It must be how the engine defines meta data for future use.

One take away, does the information in sysobjects and sysindexes get updated a run-time when we declare a variable of type AssociativeArray?

Also, what happens when two SPIDS create the same variable at the same time with different data being inserted?

That is a in-depth engine question that maybe a someone from Microsoft CAT team might know off the top of their head.

I guess I could do some research to find out.

[image]

Enclosed is a link stating that table variables use tempdb.  That is what I know is a fact.  Again, I wonder if the sys.objects and sys.indexes get updated or just place holders.

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html